# Fibonacci Sequence Proof Using limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I was trying to prove the fibonacci sequence for the golden section. But I am stuck at the following step.

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { F_{ n+1 } }{ F_{ n } }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { F_{ n } }{ F_{ n-1 } }  } =L$$

Also the recursive property says that
$$F_{ n+1 }=F_{ n }+F_{ n-1 }$$

Therefore (this step I do not understand why is happening)
$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { F_{ n }+F_{ n-1 } }{ F_{ n } }  } =1+\frac { 1 }{ L } $$

This part I can not explain or understand. I understand what is happening but I can not really make sense of this step in my head. Is there any explanation for how I can get ($1+\frac { 1 }{ L }) $.

Comment: Assuming that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=L>0$, we have $$L=\lim\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}=1+\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{L}$$ so $L>0$ has to fulfill $L=1+\frac{1}{L}$.

Comment: So, *if the limit exists*, it is the golden ratio. You just have to find some argument ensuring that the limit exists. For instance, $\left\{\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence since $$\left|\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}\right|=\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+1}}$$ and $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{F_n F_{n+1}}$$ is convergent.

Comment: As an alternative, the ratio $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ is exactly one of the convergents of the continued fraction of the golden ratio: $$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=[1;1,1,1,1,\ldots], $$ so convergence (to the golden ratio) is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}
$$
exists and equals $L>0$, you have
$$
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}}
$$
for obvious reasons. Now
$$
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}=
1+\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}=\frac{1}{L}
$$
by the theorems on limits, you're done, again by the theorems on limits:
$$
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}\right)=1+\frac{1}{L}
$$

Answer (score 2):

In addition to egreg's answer, we have

$$a_n=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$$

So,

$$a_n=1+\frac1{a_{n-1}}$$

with $a_0=1$.

So, we get the neat expansion:

$$a_n=1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1\ddots}}}$$

where there are $n$ fraction bars.  It then gives the continued fraction expansion of the golden ratio as $n\to\infty$.